# How to call a function with arguments from template in SilverStripe

Tags: php, templates, silverstripe, function-calls

Lets say I have the following function:

```
function fruit ($request) {
    ...
    $response = array('apple' => '1dollars', 'mango' => '2dollars');
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

I want to access something like `$response.apple` inside my template.

I have tried the following but this does not work as nothing shows on my page:

```
<% control response %>
    <h1>$response.apple<h2>;
<% end_control %>
```

If I try to access the function `fruit` from my template, 
`fruit` giving me an error. `fruit(request)` also gives me an error.

But if I go to fruit which is returning my data absolutely fine:

```
["apple":"1dollar","mango":"2dollar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things differently:

1. You must wrap your data array in an ArrayData or ArrayList object if you want it to be accessible in a template.
2. You must either return a raw array (in which case the template ControllerName_actionName.ss will be rendered automatically) or explicitly return a rendered template.

So more like:

```
function fruit ($request) {
    ...
    return $this->customise(array(
        'response' => new ArrayData(array(
            'apple' => '1dollars', 
            'mango' => '2dollars'
        ));
    ))->renderWith(array('YourTemplate'));
}
```

Note that the naming of "response" is totally arbitrary there. The other possible way to do it is to make "response" a method on your controller (obviously I would name it something different, I'm just keeping your names for clarity):

```
public function response() {
    return new ArrayData(array(
            'apple' => '1dollars', 
            'mango' => '2dollars'
        ));
}
```

In which case you can just return the following in your action:

```
return $this->renderWith(array('MyTemplate'));
```